# Adding an element to end of the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void    AddToEnd(double data ,int x, int y, element **list){
element *node, *tmp;
node=*list;
 if (data != 0)
 {
    tmp=malloc(sizeof(element));
    tmp->value=data;
    tmp->x_element=x;
    tmp->y_element=y;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    if (node !=NULL) {
        while (node->next != NULL) node=node->next;
        node->next=tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        *list=tmp;
    }
 }
```

}

How to get off this "if (node !=NULL)/else"? I want to add an element to the end of the list, but without this if/else which i used to adding first element.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without *if/else*?

Comment: It's just an academic example.

Comment: If it's academic, you probably should be applying your brain to it. Just use node instead of node->next in the while. I'll leave you to work out the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one level of indirection and keep a pointer to the current node. Modify the list through this pointer. The initial value is the address of the head. After that, it holds the address of the `next` field of the previous node.

```
void AddToEnd(double data, int x, int y, element **list)
{
    if (data != 0) {
        element *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));

        tmp->value = data;
        tmp->x_element = x;
        tmp->y_element = y;        
        tmp->next = NULL;

        while (*list) {
            list = &(*list)->next;
        }

        *list = tmp;
    }
}
```

This code updates the list head when the list is empty.

Comment: Note that `tmp` isn't really needed; you can use [`(*list)`](http://pastebin.com/pQL7Dgcq) if the while-loop comes first. Regardless, up-ticking the pointer-to-pointer approach, which is *frequently* helpful with various enumeration algorithms, this being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *dummy head node* in main

```
element *list = malloc(sizeof(element));
list->value=0;
list->x_element=0;
list->y_element=0;
list->next=NULL;
```

And from here on you can use the `AddToEnd` modfied (without if/else) as

```
void AddToEnd(double data ,int x, int y, element **list){
element *node, *tmp;
node=*list;
 if (data != 0)
 {
    tmp=malloc(sizeof(element));
    tmp->value=data;
    tmp->x_element=x;
    tmp->y_element=y;
    tmp->next=NULL;

    while (node->next != NULL) node=node->next;
    node->next=tmp;

 }
}
```

So your list actually starts from **second node** in **list**